# VBA - Apply Filter to Show Records for Specific Days from Today's Date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date filter that I use to display all records except for the previous days records and then I delete the "special/visible" cells after the filter is applied. This allows me to view only the data for the previous day.

Here is the line of code that applies the filter:

```
.Columns(iCol).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date))
```

I have since realized, this macro will not be run over the weekend, so on a Monday you need to show the records for Friday, Saturday & Sunday..

I thought that this would work:

```
.Columns(iCol).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -1, Date)) & CLng(DateAdd("d", -2, Date)) & CLng(DateAdd("d", -3, Date))
```

However, it does not work.. It's almost as though the filter is only looking for the previous day and not including the other 2 days as "criteria".

I know for a fact there is data for the Friday, so after the deletion, there should be data displayed, however, all the records are deleted.

Note: I could have stated in my title to look for 3 days specifically, but I would like to be able to use this code again in the event the 3 days become 4 or 5 or 6 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another criteria to remove Monday from Mondays search:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -3, Date)), Criteria2:="<>" & CLng(DateAdd("d", 0, Date))
```

Here is code for an example that I made:

```
Sub newnew()

    Dim iCol As Range
        Set iCol = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A10:B115")

    Debug.Print CLng(DateAdd("d", 0, Date))

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(DateAdd("d", -3, Date)), Criteria2:="<>" & CLng(DateAdd("d", 0, Date))
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(DateAdd("d", 1, Date))
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 .Columns(iCol).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" &  CLng(DateAdd("d", -3, Date))
```

will get all days before Friday if run on a monday - I presume you're testing for day of the week elsewhere

Comment: Thank you, this is working great.. But it is displaying today (Monday's) dates as well.. So I need today to be excluded , only need to see Friday - Sunday.. Would you be able to assist perhaps please?